# Non-isolated circuit question (connecting to notebook)

Tags: transformer, isolation

I want to build a non-isolated circuit on the protoboard and connect it to the notebook via USB port.

That is, neutral of power line/outlet will be connected to GND of USB port... in short...

I want to use a isolation transformer between the power supply of the notebook and the power line/outlet. Will my motherboard blow?

Regards.

Comment: that seems like a bad idea from a safety standpoint, but it will not damage your notebook

Comment: Make sure you don't simultaneously plug into the internet or any external device other than mouse/keyboard etc..

Comment: Connecting neutral to ground will trip an RCD. Why don't you just *not* connect neutral to ground?

Comment: Why do you need to connect neutral to ground anyway? What's the advantage of that?

Comment: @Andy aka I just need to use non-isolated way, for some reasons... I will take care with metallic parts... The question is: will the motherboard blow or not?

Comment: If there's an undetected AC fault then sure, your mobo will blow.

Comment: @Andy aka which undetected AC fault?

Comment: @Jasen do you have sure that NO?

Answer (score 1):

This is just foolish. All metallic parts on the outside of the laptop have the potential to go live. I will describe one scenario.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ66tG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A break in the neutral connection will cause the laptop to go live.*

In the event that there is a break in the neutral (and this can include a fault in the building wiring or the neutral contact of the mains plug disconnecting before the live contact does during an unplugging action) your whole circuit will go live.

- All exposed metalwork will be at mains potential.
- Various parts of the plastic insulation (touch pad, etc.) may not be rated for insulation at mains voltage.
- The DC power supply, if connected, introduces a path back to mains - even if only through the filter capacitors.
- You should never assume that neutral is at earth potential. If you get a short to live on another circuit the neutral voltage could rise to half supply voltage until the protection device trips.

Your question gives the impression that you might not listen to advice. I hope I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a good reason to connect the neutral wire of a mains supply to your usb port. That is not what it is there for. If you need a ground, use the ground wire. That is what the ground wire is for.

Neutral wires are typically connected to ground, (literally the earth) at the utility transformer, or possibly at fuse box or entry of the mains power into a building. Because wires have finite resistance, and inductance, and because a significant current may pass through them, voltages may be present on the neutral wire relative to ground at various places.

Connecting a neutral to the ground of your USB port, may cause unwanted current to flow through the USB port if other parts of your circuit are grounded correctly to the ground wire. If you are lucky, and have a ground-fault circuit breaker, that circuit breaker will break the circuit before damage is done to the USB devices or elsewhere. If you are unlucky, you don't have a ground-fault circuit breaker, or damage is done to your components before it deactivates the power.

Thus, although you may "float" your circuit on the neutral wire, you need to protect it from coming in contact with any *actual* ground. Doesn't sound like a good idea. Much better to use the ground wire. That is what it is there for.